# Android Photos App Share Intent

Tags: android, android-intent, sdk, google-plus

Recently I noticed that in the new Google Photos app that replaced the older Gallery app that comes with Android has a much better looking share intent chooser that I have not found in any other app. How can I replicate this for my own applications? Is this related to Google Plus?

[image]

Comment: did you found an answer?

Comment: I was just about to ask the same thing??

Comment: I have an answer now, it's part of the support library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26721403/android-how-to-implement-bottom-sheet-from-material-design-docs/35615022#35615022) it's now a part of the [Android Support Library](http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/index.html) since version 23.2.0.

Answer (score 1):

I just found this => [BottomSheet](https://github.com/soarcn/BottomSheet) I think it could be useful for you !