# Android How to implement Bottom Sheet from Material Design docs

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, material-design, floating-action-button

How do you implement the bottom sheet specficiation? 
http://www.google.com/design/spec/components/bottom-sheets.html

The new update to Google Drive shows this with the Floating Action Button press ->

[image]

Granted the specs never say anything about rounded corners, regardless it is possible to do, just unsure of how to go about it. Currently using the AppCompat library and target set to 21.

Thanks

Comment: Link is broken. New link https://material.io/design/components/sheets-bottom.html#usage

Answer (score 66, accepted):

Answering my own question so developers know that the new support library provides this finally! All hail the all powerful Google!

An example from the [Android Developer's Blog](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2016/02/android-support-library-232.html):

> ```
> // The View with the BottomSheetBehavior
> View bottomSheet = coordinatorLayout.findViewById(R.id.bottom_sheet);  
> BottomSheetBehavior behavior = BottomSheetBehavior.from(bottomSheet);  
> behavior.setBottomSheetCallback(new BottomSheetCallback() {  
>    @Override  
>    public void onStateChanged(@NonNull View bottomSheet, int newState) {  
>      // React to state change  
>    }  
>
>   @Override  
>   public void onSlide(@NonNull View bottomSheet, float slideOffset) {  
>      // React to dragging events  
>   }  
> });
> ```

@reVerse's [answer above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26723695/1784299) is still a valid option but its nice to know that there is a standard that Google supports too.

Comment: Thanks for posting. I think this should be the "Correct" answer now :)

Comment: @androiddeveloper done. considering its a support specific thing now, I feel users will have better luck looking for those examples. When I asked the question originally it wasn't provided in the support lib.

If the question was "How to implement Support Library bottom sheet view" then I would've provided a more in depth answer too :)

Comment: @JohnShelley Don't you need to use some XML stuff too? Is it possible to set the bottom sheet peek/collapsed (or whatever it's called about when it's at the bottom) to have a wrap-content view , and when it's expanded, to be full screen?

Comment: I think there are many people wondering how to use Google new support API, and Vipul Shah has a great YouTube link that can help you understand how to use it, please refer to the YouTube link in http://stackoverflow.com/a/35731959/1053037

Comment: the question remains: how to implement the bottom sheet menu. Where are menu items in the example above??????? You know, the menu items that you click ...

Answer (score 67):

## Edit

The `BottomSheet` is now part of the `android-support-library`. See [John Shelleys' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35615022/982852).

---

Unfortunately there's currently no "official" way on how to do this (at least none that I'm aware of).
Luckily there's a library called ["BottomSheet" (click)](https://github.com/soarcn/BottomSheet) which mimics the look and feel of the `BottomSheet` and supports Android 2.1 and up.

In case of the Drive app, here's how the code would look like with this library:

```
    new BottomSheet.Builder(this, R.style.BottomSheet_Dialog)
            .title("New")
            .grid() // <-- important part
            .sheet(R.menu.menu_bottom_sheet)
            .listener(new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            // TODO
        }
    }).show();
```

**menu_bottom_sheet** (basically a standard /res/menu/*.xml resource)

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/folder"
        android:title="Folder"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_folder" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/upload"
        android:title="Upload"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_file_upload" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/scan"
        android:title="Scan"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_camera_alt" />
</menu>
```

---

Output looks like this:

[image: picture of the bottom sheet]

Which, I think, comes pretty close to the original. If you're not happy with the colors you can customize it - [see this (click)](https://github.com/soarcn/BottomSheet#style).

Comment: Boom. This is exactly what I'm looking for! I'll give it a try tonight!

Comment: this is great, thanks for sharing! What if you want to display all options that would show up in a share intent? They would be dynamically generated based on the apps installed on the device. Any thoughts on how that  can be accomplished?

Comment: @Cat Well basically you just need to get a List of all applications that can handle the intent (see [this StackO-Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9083826/get-the-list-of-apps-capable-of-handling-the-send-intent-to-display-in-a-view-n) for example) and add them to the adapter which "feeds" the BottomSheet. You can also see the official sample of the lib which does exactly what you're requesting. ([Click - Line 153 - 179](https://github.com/soarcn/BottomSheet/blob/master/example/src/main/java/com/cocosw/bottomsheet/example/ListAcitivty.java)).

Comment: that worked, thanks @reVerse! I ended up reusing the code in the `getShareActions` method to get all possible sharing options. Btw, also useful to call `.limit(R.integer.num_share_actions)` on the builder unless you want the sheet to cover the entire screen

Comment: This library is so awesome !

Comment: @reVerse I want to implement Bottom sheet with a fab icon as given in android material specs. (http://bit.ly/1O8EQrK). Is it possible with this library?

Comment: @KoustuvSinha I don't think so. The screenshot you've posted looks more like a Fragment with a custom view that gets translated onto the screen than a menu which this library basically tries to replicate.

Comment: @KoustuvSinha Have a look at the [AndroidSlidingUpPanel](https://github.com/umano/AndroidSlidingUpPanel) library.

Comment: @reVerse I ended up accepting the Google Support Library as the correct answer just so we don't confuse any new visitors to this question. The answer you posted is definitely still valid though! I hope thats okay.

Comment: @JohnShelley That's all right,  absolutely. I'd also recommend going for the "official solution" though it's really limited at the moment but at least Google laid the foundation, finally.  ;)

Comment: it's ALMOST perfect. One thing is when selecting an item in menu, the background of that item turns into NASTY Yellow/Orange color. Any idea how to change it???

Answer (score 8):

Following the blog post: http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2016/02/android-support-library-232.html

My xml ended up looking like this:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/coordinator_layout"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/bottom_sheet"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_behavior="android.support.design.widget.BottomSheetBehavior">
        <ImageView
            android:src="@android:drawable/ic_input_add"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

And in my onCreateView of my fragment:

```
    coordinatorLayout = (CoordinatorLayout)v.findViewById(R.id.coordinator_layout);
    View bottomSheet = coordinatorLayout.findViewById(R.id.bottom_sheet);
    BottomSheetBehavior behavior = BottomSheetBehavior.from(bottomSheet);
    behavior.setPeekHeight(100);
    behavior.setBottomSheetCallback(new BottomSheetBehavior.BottomSheetCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onStateChanged(@NonNull View bottomSheet, int newState) {
            // React to state change
        }

        @Override
        public void onSlide(@NonNull View bottomSheet, float slideOffset) {
            // React to dragging events
        }
    });
```

The default of setPeekHeight is 0, so if you don't set it, you won't be able to see your view.

Comment: Yes, the xml is exactly the way my fragment looked. Is it not working for you?

Comment: The default peek height is -1 (AUTO!), not 0.

Comment: If you will use AndroidX keep in mind the package name change: `com.google.android.material.bottomsheet.BottomSheetBehavior`

Comment: where are the menu items?????????????????? (the whole point of bottom sheet menu)

Answer (score 7):

You can now use Official `BottomSheetBehavior` API from android support library 23.2.

Below is sample code snippet

```
bottomSheetBehavior = BottomSheetBehavior.from(findViewById(R.id.bottomSheet));

case R.id.expandBottomSheetButton:
 bottomSheetBehavior.setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED);
 break;
case R.id.collapseBottomSheetButton:
 bottomSheetBehavior.setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_COLLAPSED);
 break;
case R.id.hideBottomSheetButton:
 bottomSheetBehavior.setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_HIDDEN);
 break;
case R.id.showBottomSheetDialogButton:
 new MyBottomSheetDialogFragment().show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "sample");
```

Comment: Hi Vipul , thanks for the link. I have one question though. Is it possible to set an anchor point for the bottom sheet?

Comment: Awesome youtube link. Do you have the source code in a public repo somewhere?

Answer (score 5):

I would go with a straight corners as it is in the guidelines. As for the implementation - maybe it is best to use the idea from this project: https://github.com/umano/AndroidSlidingUpPanel

I think that you could use it as it is or take the idea for the implementation.
Another great article on how to implement similar sliding panel can be found here:
http://blog.neteril.org/blog/2013/10/10/framelayout-your-best-ui-friend/

Answer (score 5):

Here are some of the other options :

- There is one available from [Flipboard](https://github.com/Flipboard/bottomsheet), however the embedding activity
  needs to be modified for the bottomsheet to work.
- tutti-ch's [bottomsheet](https://github.com/tutti-ch/android-bottomsheet) : This has been extracted from Android Repo's ResolverActivity and the launching activity need not be modified.

Answer (score 3):

[image: Bottom Sheet image]

If you want to achieve bottom sheet like this, follow this design pattern
few simple steps

1. create `bottom_sheet_layout.xml` layout file
2. create `bottom_sheet_background.xml` drawable file

set your `bottom_sheet_background.xml` drawable file like this

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:shape="rectangle">
    
        <solid android:color="@color/bottom_sheet_background"/>
        <corners
            android:topRightRadius="20dp"
            android:topLeftRadius="20dp"/>
    
    </shape>
```

your `bottom_sheet_layout.xml`

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/bottom_Sheet"
        android:background="@drawable/bottom_sheet_background"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingStart="24dp"
        android:paddingEnd="24dp"
        android:paddingTop="16dp"
        android:paddingBottom="42dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/rectangle_3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:background="@drawable/rectangle_39"
            />
    
    
        //add your design code here
    
    </LinearLayout>
```

And your `activity_main.xml` or fragment

```
    <androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    
    
       //design your code here
    
    
        //this is your bottom sheet layout included here
        <include
            android:id="@+id/bottom_sheet_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_behavior="com.google.android.material.
            bottomsheet.BottomSheetBehavior"
            layout="@layout/bottom_sheet_layout"/>
    
    </androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Finally, add code in your `MainActivity` or `Fragment` class. Here I am adding Kotlin code inside your `onCreate` or `onCreateView`

```
BottomSheetBehavior.from(binding.bottomSheetLayout.bottomSheet).apply {
    //peek height is default visible height
    peekHeight = 200
    this.state = BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_COLLAPSED
}
```

That's it!

Answer (score 0):

Google recently released [Android Support Library 23.2](http://android-developers.blogspot.co.at/2016/02/android-support-library-232.html) which officially brings [Bottom sheets](https://www.google.com/design/spec/components/bottom-sheets.html) to the Android Design Support Library.

Comment: Is there any sample/tutorial for this?

Answer (score -1):

Now with Android Jetpack Compose released which is Android's modern UI toolkit , Bottomsheets can be made more easily without using any xml code:-

1.To create Persistent bottom sheet where user **can** access the content outside of the bottom sheet’s scope:-

[image]

```
val bottomSheetScaffoldState = rememberBottomSheetScaffoldState(
    bottomSheetState = BottomSheetState(BottomSheetValue.Collapsed)
)
val coroutineScope = rememberCoroutineScope()
MaterialTheme {
    Column {
        BottomSheetScaffold(
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
            topBar = { TopAppBar(viewModel, onNavigateToRecipeListScreen, hideKeyBoard) },
            content = {
                CreateRecipeContent(
                    viewModel,
                    context,
                    readExternalStorage,
                    bottomSheetScaffoldState,
                    coroutineScope
                )
            },
            scaffoldState = bottomSheetScaffoldState,
            sheetContent = {
                Column(
                    Modifier
                        .fillMaxWidth()
                        .height(200.dp)
                        .background(color = colorResource(id = R.color.colorPrimaryLight))
                )
                {
                    Text(
                        text = "SELECT PICTURE",
                        style = TextStyle(fontSize = 26.sp),
                        fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold,
                        modifier = Modifier
                            .padding(8.dp)
                            .align(Alignment.Start),
                        color = Color.Black
                    )
                    Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(16.dp))
                    IconButton(onClick = {
                        when {
                            context.let { it1 ->
                                ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(
                                    it1,
                                    Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
                                )
                            } == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED -> {
                                val takePictureIntent =
                                    Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE)
                                launchCamera(takePictureIntent)
                                coroutineScope.launch {
                                    bottomSheetScaffoldState.bottomSheetState.collapse()
                                }
                            }
                            else -> {
                                // You can directly ask for the permission.
                                // The registered ActivityResultCallback gets the result of this request.
                                viewModel.isCameraPermissionAsked = true
                                readExternalStorage()
                                coroutineScope.launch {
                                    bottomSheetScaffoldState.bottomSheetState.collapse()
                                }
                            }
                        }

                    }, modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()) {
                        Text(
                            text = "TAKE PHOTO",
                            style = TextStyle(fontSize = 20.sp),
                            fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold,
                            modifier = Modifier
                                .padding(8.dp)
                                .align(Alignment.Start),
                            textAlign = TextAlign.Left,
                            color = Color.Black
                        )
                    }
                    Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(16.dp))
                    IconButton(onClick = {
                        when {
                            context.let { it1 ->
                                ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(
                                    it1,
                                    Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
                                )
                            } == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED -> {
                                val galleryIntent = Intent(
                                    Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                                    MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI
                                )
                                galleryIntent.type = "image/*"
                                launchGalley(galleryIntent)
                                coroutineScope.launch {
                                    bottomSheetScaffoldState.bottomSheetState.collapse()
                                }
                            }
                            else -> {
                                // You can directly ask for the permission.
                                // The registered ActivityResultCallback gets the result of this request.
                                viewModel.isCameraPermissionAsked = false
                                readExternalStorage()
                                coroutineScope.launch {
                                    bottomSheetScaffoldState.bottomSheetState.collapse()
                                }
                            }
                        }

                    }, modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()) {
                        Text(
                            text = "CHOOSE FROM GALLERY",
                            style = TextStyle(fontSize = 20.sp),
                            fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold,
                            modifier = Modifier
                                .padding(8.dp)
                                .align(Alignment.Start),
                            textAlign = TextAlign.Left,
                            color = Color.Black
                        )
                    }

                }
            }, sheetPeekHeight = 0.dp
        )


    }
}
```

Above code snipped and screenshot is from the app:-

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.bhuvnesh.diary

created entirely using Jetpack Compose by me

2. To create Modal Bottom Sheet where users **cannot** access the content out of the bottom sheet’s scope:-

   ```
    ModalBottomSheetLayout(
        sheetState = modalBottomSheetState,
        sheetElevation = 8.dp,
        sheetContent = {
            //sheet content
        }
    ) {
        ...
        //main content
    }
   ```