# Android material bottomsheet example

Tags: java, android, android-layout, material-design, android-compatibility

I would like to implement a bottom sheet layout in my android app as per the [new design guidelines](http://www.google.com/design/spec/components/bottom-sheets.html#bottom-sheets-persistent-bottom-sheets), however I cant find any info anywhere to do this natively, has anyone done this in their app using android studio that could point me in the right direction? Any help will go a long way thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26723695/3541465  checkout this answer

Comment: So this hasn't been built into Android yet I guess?

Comment: There's another non-native from Flipboard https://github.com/Flipboard/bottomsheet

Comment: @edmund yes it hasn't