# Material Design how Google Maps

Tags: android, google-maps, material-design

I am developing an application similar to Google Maps. I want that when clicked on the marker bottom panel, it should go to the information and just like the Google Maps it should scroll up and fill to full screen. Please tell me how they have done it? and how it can be implemented?

[image: Bottom panel]

---

[image: Scroll]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the sliding up scroll you can use the SlidingUpPanel by umano.
[GitHub](https://github.com/umano/AndroidSlidingUpPanel)

Answer (score 9):

Well now no need to use third-party libraries. Now its called as [Bottom Sheets](http://www.google.com/design/spec/components/bottom-sheets.html) which is introduced in [Design Support Library 23.2](http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2016/02/android-support-library-232.html).

You can have look into [SO : Android How to implement Bottom Sheet from Material Design docs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26721403/android-how-to-implement-bottom-sheet-from-material-design-docs)

Comment: @war_Hero nope, one thing is bottomSheet, another thing is the image that  came up when you are dragging the bottomSheet

Comment: @MiguelHincapieC that can be part of your bottom sheet UI.

Comment: Yeah, you are right, but no idea if OP got "all behavior like" google maps or just the bottomsheet, because I have not found a well explained example of it (the image that comes up when sliding up) using official bottomsheet.