# BottomSheet appearing from the top

Tags: java, android

How can I show a BottomSheet from the top instead of the bottom?

```
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            mBottomSheetBehavior.setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED);
        }
    });

    mBottomSheetBehavior = BottomSheetBehavior.from(bottomSheetLayout);
```

Comment: You have to write your own BottomSheetBehaviour. Look into the implementation from support library and modify it according to your needs.

Comment: Use custom bottom sheet. Check this - 1) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26721403/android-how-to-implement-bottom-sheet-from-material-design-docs  2) http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2016/02/android-support-library-232.html

Answer (score 0):

I think you may want a 'top' version of `BottomSheetBehavior`.

[Use this](https://github.com/ipuris/AndroidTopSheet/blob/master/library/src/main/java/com/github/techisfun/android/topsheet/TopSheetBehavior.java)

Above code is forked from the [original repository](https://github.com/TechIsFun/AndroidTopSheet), but I fixed some library dependencies (old `android.support` library -> `androidx` library) for latest version of Android.