# How to add ListView to snackbar?

Tags: android, android-snackbar

While playing with the youtube app I noticed this view appear when I clicked a button:

[image]

Is this a snackbar (white view at the bottom of screen) and if so how do I customise a normal snackbar to look like it?

Comment: I think it is a Bottom Sheet

Answer (score 1):

These are bottom sheets, specifically modal bottom sheets. See the documentation here: https://material.google.com/components/bottom-sheets.html?authuser=0#bottom-sheets-modal-bottom-sheets

You'll need to add a `LinearLayout` that acts as your `BottomSheet` to a parent view of a `CoordinatorLayout`

Comment: Thanks for the help, I will now check out how to implement this.

Comment: The material documentation isn't very helpful as it doesn't provide any examples. You'll have more help here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26721403/android-how-to-implement-bottom-sheet-from-material-design-docs/35615022#35615022