# How this component is called, and how to implement it

Tags: android, user-interface

Android get hidden screen from bottom when long pressing system "home" button.

[image]

When I long press on the home , a view comes from bottom , which can be scrollable, I want to do that in my app. please suggest me, how to do.

Comment: Are you asking how to create a list display (by clicking some new button you create)? Or are you asking how to override the system home button?

Comment: I am asking how to create like that only.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android How to implement Bottom Sheet from Material Design docs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26721403/android-how-to-implement-bottom-sheet-from-material-design-docs)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The component is called "Bottom Sheet"

So your question is a meta-question of [Android How to implement Bottom Sheet from Material Design docs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26721403/android-how-to-implement-bottom-sheet-from-material-design-docs).

a full description and documentation can be found [here](https://material.google.com/components/bottom-sheets.html#).