# Show and Hide Bottom Sheet Programmatically

Tags: android, material-design, bottom-sheet

I have implemented Bottom Sheet functionality within my activity in onCreate() using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26723695) solution and [this](https://github.com/soarcn/BottomSheet) library

```
   sheet = new BottomSheet.Builder(this, R.style.BottomSheet_Dialog)
        .title("New")
        .grid() // <-- important part
        .sheet(R.menu.menu_bottom_sheet)
        .listener(new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        // TODO
    }
}).build();
```

Now, I would like to Show Bottom sheet, on click of button and in a same way want to hide bottom sheet on click of same button, if already Visible

Comment: Hello sista, I think you can do that by sheet.show() and sheet.dismiss() based on whether the view is visible or not.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Inside your `onClick()` of the button use: `sheet.show()`.

Then when you want to dismiss it, use `sheet.dismiss()`;

Here below a possible solution:

```
BottomSheet sheet = new BottomSheet.Builder(...).build();
Button button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.mybutton);
button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        //you can use isShowing() because BottomSheet inherit from Dialog class
        if (sheet.isShowing()){
            sheet.dismiss();
        } else {
            sheet.show();    
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 76):

To close the **BottomSheetDialogFragment** from inside the fragment you can call:

```
dismiss();
```

To show or hide the **BottomSheetDialogFragment** from the activity you can simply call:

```
bottomSheetDialogFragment.dismiss();//to hide it
bottomSheetDialogFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(),tag);// to show it
```

Comment: I use `bottomSheetBehavior.setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED)` to show it.

Answer (score 19):

For showing the Bottom Sheet use this code:

```java
bottomSheetInfoBehavior.setHideable(false);
bottomSheetInfoBehavior.setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED);
```

For Hiding the Bottom sheet use this code:

```java
bottomSheetInfoBehavior.setHideable(true);
bottomSheetInfoBehavior.setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_HIDDEN);
```

Answer (score 9):

If you want hide from within a Fragment then use

```
this.dismiss();
```

or

```
YOUR_FRAGMENT.this.dismiss()
```

Comment: Just call dismiss method
'dismiss()'