# How to slide down BottomSheetDialogFragment by backpressed from activity?

Tags: android

opening slide up bottomsheet by below code

```
VillazBottomSheet villazBottomSheet=new VillazBottomSheet();
villazBottomSheet.setArguments(bundle);
villazBottomSheet.show(getSupportFragmentManager(),"VillazList");//slideup and open sheet
```

Now i want to slide down this fragment by backpressed

```
@Override
    public void onBackPressed()
    {
        villazBottomSheet.slidedown()// I want to do this
    }
```

How can I do this ?
[what i had tried](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gJKOJ.png)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Show and Hide Bottom Sheet Programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42293488/show-and-hide-bottom-sheet-programmatically)

Comment: i tried it, it not slide bottom, it directly disappears from acivity

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
BottomSheetBehavior.from(villazBottomSheet).setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_COLLAPSED)
```

Comment: please see my question again ,I  tried it