# Bottom Sheet Text Color and Appearance

Tags: android, material-design, bottom-sheet

I have followed this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26723695/3585072) and [this](https://github.com/soarcn/BottomSheet) library to implement `Bottom Sheet` functionality and best part is I have successfully integrated the same one.

Now I have *three* small queries:

1. I want to set **text color** as Black and Bold
2. I want to **divide Grid** in *3 columns* only (as still showing 4 items in first row and 2 items in second row - In case of Tablets)
3. I want to **put divider** between Grid items

**Code:**

```
new BottomSheet.Builder(this, R.style.BottomSheet_Dialog)
            .title("Choose")
            .grid()
            .sheet(R.menu.menu_bottom_sheet)
            .listener(new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            // TODO
        }
    }).show();
```

Comment: use inbuild bottom sheet provided by Android API

Comment: see this example http://www.truiton.com/2016/07/android-bottom-sheet-example/